# Observable: onCompletion not called after http get with error

Tags: javascript, http, rxjs, observable

I can't understand why onCompletion is not called when an error occures (e.g http 401/404). Shouldn't be the expected behaviour?

```
this.http.get('http://localhost/xxx')
  .map((res) => res.json())
  .subscribe(
    (res) => {
      console.log('onSuccess');
      console.log(res);
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log('onError');
      console.log(err);
    },
    () => {
      console.log('onCompletion');
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In an Observable Execution, zero to infinite Next notifications may be delivered. If either an Error or Complete notification is delivered, then nothing else can be delivered afterwards.

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#executing-observables

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 types of events:

- next
- error
- complete

And they occur according to this (RegExp) scheme: `n*(e|c)`

The documentation states this too, as Julia points out.